# OnSelect dosnt work with react-Google-places-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, google-api

I build a form with react js and i want to include location with google-auto complete , so i found this library :

https://github.com/Tintef/react-google-places-autocomplete#readme

Its worked fine for me for 2 weeks but suddenly I see nothing while I print the value of OnSelect.
at my console this message in yellow pops-up:

```
Select-073d29ba.esm.js:749 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
```

my Component:

```
<div>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      onSelect={console.log}
 />
```

Suggestion what happend?

Comment: I don't know what happend, but im using 'react-google-autocomplete' and its nice, in react-google-autocomplete its "onPlaceSelected" and not onSelect.

Comment: I tried 'react-google-autocomplete' but there a lot of cities that the library cant locate. Try for example "Tel-aviv", does it work for you?

Comment: Yea, it works. Also in hebrew. you have to add "types" to the <Autocomplete /> component - types={['geocode']}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, the problem is that the latest version of react-google-places-autocomplete is still in ALPHA and BETA Testing and it is not a stable one.

Just use the version 2.3.2, it will solve the issue.

run the command :

> npm install --save react-google-places-autocomplete@2.3.2